# informatica mapping parameter with default value

Tags: parameters, mapping, task, informatica

I have session task which is called in multiple workflow.currently the target in all the workflow is DB.

The mapping in the task has a router transformation to perform data load based on a condition

There is a requirement for the first time to write to a file instead of DB and the filename is dynamic

I have created a mapping parameter $$outputfilename to pass it via parameter file and was able to write to a file  but the rest of the workflow which loads to the db are failing with the below error 
Message: Session task instance [RUNNER] : [VAR_27026 Error: Missing initial value for session parameter:[$OutputFileName].]

how can we assign a dummy filename for all the workflow which writes to the db.i dont want to add it in the parameter file as we may have more workflows coming in future .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is some discrepancy between the 2 variable names $$outputfilename and $OutputFileName which is mentioned in the error message... this makes me think that the real problem is that you have configured your reusable session task to output to a target file by default rather than configuring it to write to a db table by default and then overriding just the single session instance within the workflow which writes to file. Please check this